# Connecting android with sql internal and external server

Tags: android, sql-server

I am trying to connect sql server which is on internet with my android app I'm getting error

> E/error here 1 :: Unknown server host name
>   'sv38.dbsqlserver.com,8888'. sv38.dbsqlserver.com,8888 this is my ip
>   for connection

Comment: hei, can you add your configuration code for connect your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you forgot to add to the internet permission on your AndroidManifest.xml.

just add this to your AndroidManifest, before

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I've add these two permissions in first place still getting that error

Comment: first you can change sv38.dbsqlserver.com,8888 to sv38.dbsqlserver.com:8888, if still getting error .i was ping your host and callback is 64 bytes from 173-231-33-58.sv18.premiumwebserver.com (173.231.33.58). you can change your host to 173-231-33-58.sv18.premiumwebserver.com or u can use IP 173.231.33.58

Comment: Thankyou it worked I used sv38.dbsqlserver.com:8888.

Comment: @user9317926 yeey! please upvote my comment or answer for help someone else :)

Comment: do you any idea to how to fetch data from sql to android as I'm trying to do it with my sql server